# SUMIFs between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to conduct a SUMIF between excel workbooks. Ideally, my procedure will count the sum of column J when column H = "Emma" (in the Dataset workbook) and return the value in cell B3 of the Summary sheet in the Monthly Report workbook. Here's what I have so far:

```
 Sub CalculateEmma()

'range for calc
Dim EmmaBalance As Long

EmmaBalance = Workbooks("Dataset.xlsx").Worksheets("Summary").SumIf(Range("H:H"), "Emma", Range("J:J"))

Workbooks("Monthly Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Summary").Range("B3") = EmmaBalance

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second line is wrong. It should be:

```
EmmaBalance = Application.Worksheetfunction.SumIf(Workbooks("Dataset.xlsx").Worksheets("Summary").Range("H:H"), "Emma", Workbooks("Dataset.xlsx").Worksheets("Summary").Range("J:J"))
```